# In Rails how to use a model's method for the active record `where`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Normally we use `Model.where(name: 'John')` to find records. Let's say I have a method inside the model named `status` which does some calculations and output a string. How can I use that in the `where`? Now if I use `Model.where(status: 'active')` it says `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column model.status does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. `where` is for SQL conditions, if you calculate your `status` in Ruby, you can't use it in `where`.

Comment: Then what can i do? The only option is to loop through each item and get the matching ones to an array right?

Comment: You have two possibilities. Either you have to use `to_a` on your relation and then `select` method to select ones with proper status or (if you care about performance) you can write your status counting in SQL and put it in `where`.

Answer (score 1):

If what you ask is how to have `status` applied as a filter by the SQL server before retrieving the records, you can't.

- One option indeed, is to retrieve all the records and then use select to get what you want. That is very inefficient.
- One other option is to write a fragment of SQL logic and plug that straight into a where. That is not easy but very efficient.
- One last solution is to have that status be computer for you by a `before_save` and stored in the table. You can then use a regular where to filter which records you want. The downside of this, is that you have a new extra column.